# Swift: How to get async data before method returns?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying work use the following plugin for a grid layout. https://github.com/ecerney/CollectionViewWaterfallLayout

It requires me to return a cgsize for each cell with the actual image size.

So I'm trying to get to the size with another cocoapod plugin:

https://github.com/IMcD23/IMRemoteImageSize/

but, "getImageSize" is an async call to get the image I believe. Therefore each time return value for cgsize is "nil". Is there a way for me to get the size before the return function executes? Thanks!

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let image = images[indexPath.row]

    var sizeOfTopCover:CGSize?

    UIImage.getImageSize(image.url, completion: {


        (size) -> Void in
        print("Got size of image: \(image.url): \(size)")

        sizeOfTopCover = size

    })

    return sizeOfTopCover! <<< breaking here

}
```

Comment: You can't return the value since it is retrieved asynchronously; essentially if you already knew the answer then you wouldn't need to ask the question. You should fetch the image before you layout the collection view, or put a placeholder image that is replaced when you fetch the image. Something like SDWebImage can help you

Answer (score 0):

You must be know size when call

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
```

But you can reload your collection view when received sizes for all cells.
Or reload each cell when you received size for cell.

Comment: Are you saying that i can just leave an arbitrary CGSize(100,100)? How would i reload the size of the cell? Wouldn't this be bad when scrolling through the view to see the size instantly shift?

Comment: reload the size of the cell - `collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)])`

Comment: user805981,  this be bad when scrolling. My solutions - loading consist from 3 steps. 1 - init collectionView with 0 cells, and loading sizes for cells. 2 - reload collectionView with N element witch have size. 3 - when cell appear start loading image (with SDWebImage for example).

Comment: Where should "collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)])" be at? is it per cell that has been dequeued?

Comment: @user805981, `UIImage.getImageSize(image.url, completion: { **here! ;)** })` but u must to check whether you have a size, that don't repeat UIImage.getImageSize